# python manage.py sql Unknown command

Tags: django-models, manage.py

When i run following command:-
python manage.py sql

i get an error stating that

Unknown command: 'sql'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

version :- python manage.py --version
1.10

Answer (score 1):

First do a make migrations

`python manage.py makemigrations app_name`

Apply migrations

`python manage.py migrate`

Instead of using `python manage.py sql app_name`

Comment: latest django doesn't support one liner command instead needs two lines first create migration and then dump migrate to db.

Answer (score 0):

That is working. There is no 'sql' command. We're you thinking of 'sqlmigrate' maybe? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/